# Why don't kills for the Phantom Assignment go up?

Tags: battlefield-4

Does anyone know why the kills for the phantom assignment won't go up in game or in battlelog? I've tried everything to get them to appear.

Answer (score 1):

This question has several possible answers depending on which of the Phantom assignments you are referencing.

If you haven't activated the Phantom Prospect assignment:

- While logged into Battlelog click on the "Leaderboards" tab.
- Click the small skull icon found in the lower left of this page. [image: Stage 1 Skull]
- Once you are able to enter text type **bumpinthenight** (some users have had issue with using Firefox for this so consider Chrome or IE if it doesn't activate).
- You've activated the Phantom Prospect assignment and can now track the requirements in the Assignments tab.

The process for Phantom Initiate (the next step) is similar:

- follow the same steps as above to find the skull and this time enter **epic dream worlds** when prompted.

The Phantom Initiate phase of the project is activated similarly:

- follow the same steps as above to find the skull and this time enter **24344241893** when prompted.

If you have completed all the Phantom assignments and you are wondering why the kills are not counting with your new bow you most likely didn't pick up the papers on top of the filing cabinet in the bow room inside "Hangar 21".
[image: Phantom Operative Orders]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey Excession, welcome to Arqade! Can you summarise the 'how to activate' stuff in the link? That way, if the link is taken down, the information is still handy here :)

Comment: I went ahead and fleshed out the answer to cover things in a bit more detail.  Let me know if anything more is desired ;)

Comment: Perfect, this is done really well :)

Answer (score 1):

Click on the assignment and it says what u need to do.

It will say something like this:

- 200 pistol kills.
- 100 lmg kills.
- 2 shotgun ribons.

You will need to do them in order, ie the pistol kills first, then the lmg and then the shotgun ribons.

It will not track the lmg kills if you have not done the pistol kills first.